# How do I make a nested loop continue only after a asynchronous function has been resolved or how do I extend ".then" beyond the scope

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, jszip

I tried to prevent async problems with promises in the following code. By using a .then function everything within that function gets called after the function has been resolved. But now I have the problem that neither can I extend the scope of the ".then function" enough to include the bits after the second loop nor can I to my knowledge easily pause the code until the function has been properly resolved and THEN continue with the loop iteration.

Here's my main code(simplified):

```
let total = []
$.each(element, function(data) {
  //Some other code
  let out;
  $.each(element2, function(data2) {
    getZip(data2).then(function(txt){ //after everything has finished this get's called
      out = someFunction(txt,data2);
      total.push(out);
    });

  )};
   console.log(total)//this gets called first 
  //some other code that does some stuff with total
)};
```

Here's the getZip code which is asynchronous:

```
        function getZip(zipFile) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
                zip = new JSZip()
                JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent("someURL/" + zipFile, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err)
                    }
                    JSZip.loadAsync(data).then(function (zip) {
                        return zip.file(zipFile.replace(".zip", "")).async("text"); //gets the file within the zip andoutputs as text
                    }).then(function (txt) {
                        resolve(txt)
                    });

                });
            });
        }
```

I'd be happy if either the getZip code could be made synchronous or if the before mentioned could be done.

Comment: could wrap the loop in an anonymous async function and await the promise, or in your loop push promises to array then call `promise.all()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think I fully understand the code you have written. However, I recommend you use `Promise.all`. Here is an example I have written that I hope helps guide you:

```js
let total = [];
$.each([1,2,3,4], function (data) {
  // Some other code.
  let out;
  // Create a new promise so that we can wait on the getZip method.
  new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {  
    // Create a holder variable. This variable with hold all the promises that are output from the getZip method you have.
    let gZipPromises = [];
    $.each([5,6,7,8], function (data2) {    
      // Your getZip method would go here. wrap the call to getZip in gZipPromises.push to push all the returned promises onto the holding variable.
      gZipPromises.push(new Promise(function (resolve2, reject2) { 
        // Sample Code
        setTimeout(function () {
         total.push(data2); 
          resolve2(""); 
        }, 10);
        // End Sample Code.
      }));
    });  
    // Pass the holding variable to Promise.all so that all promises in the holding variable are executed before resolving.
    Promise.all(gZipPromises).then(function() { 
      resolve() 
    });
  }).then(function () {
    // This will be called only when all getZip promises are completed in the second loop.
    console.log(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

With that said, I could not test your code. But I think this would work:
(Please note that based on the code you provided, the variable `total` would be logged for each iteration of the top most `$.each`

```js
let total = []
$.each(element, function(data) {
  //Some other code
  let out;  
  // Define a new promise.
  new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    let gZipPromises = [];
    $.each(element2, function(data2) {
      gZipPromises.push(
        getZip(data2).then(function(txt){ //after everything has finished this get's called
          out = someFunction(txt,data2);
          total.push(out);
        });
      );
    )};
    Promise.all(gZipPromises).then(function() { 
      resolve() 
    });
  }).then(function () { 
    console.log(total)
  });  
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const elements = [["foo.zip"],["bar.zip"],["baz.zip"]];
const totalOut = getAllZips(elements)
  .then(text => console.info(text))
  .catch(error => console.error(error))

function someFunction(text, data) {
  return `${text}\nLength: ${data.length}`;
}

async function getAllZips(elements) {
  let promises = [];
  for(const element of elements) {
    for(const data of element) {
      promises.push(getZip(data).then(text => {
        return someFunction(text, data);
      }));
    }
  }
  return Promise.all(promises);
}

async function getZip(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(`someURL/${file}`, async (err, data) => {
      try {
        if (err) throw err;
        const zip = await JSZip.loadAsync(data);
        const name = file.replace(".zip", "");
        resolve(await zip.file(name).async('text'));
      } catch(error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script>/*IGNORE*/const JSZipUtils = {getBinaryContent:(p,c)=>errs.gbc?c(new Error('gbc'),null):c(null,{foo:true})};const JSZip = {loadAsync:(d)=>errs.la?Promise.reject(new Error('la')):({file:n=>({async:a=>errs.a?Promise.reject(new Error('a')):Promise.resolve('Hello World')})})};const errs = {gbc:false,la:false,a:false};/*IGNORE*/</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of sounds like a use case for async iterator generators, but maybe I'm just over-engineering.  You have a bunch of resources that you want to iterate over and their contents are asynchronous.  You want it to "look" synchronous, so you can leverage async/await:

```js
function getZip(zipFile) {
  /*
   * Theres no point in simplifying this function since it looks like
   * the JSZip API deals with callbacks and not Promises.
   */
  return Promise.resolve(zipFile);
}

function someFn(a, b) {
  return `${a}: ${b.length}`;
}

async function* zipper(elements) {
  for (const element of elements) {
    for (const data of element) {
      const txt = await getZip(data);
      yield someFn(txt, data);
    }
  }
}

(async() => {
  const elements = [
    ["hello"],
    ["world"],
    ["foo"],
    ["bar"]
  ];
  let total = [];
  for await (const out of zipper(elements)) {
    total.push(out);
  }
  console.log(total);
})();
```